# CKeditor: Allow choosing CSS classes from a select menu in dialogs

Tags: wysiwyg

The idea is to make it easier for content managers, restricting them to choose a CSS class between a preconfigured list.

This feature is already available using the WYSIWYG module (see screenshot https://groups.drupal.org/files/ckeditor-css-config.png) but not using the CKEditor module.

I'm not sure if there is already a contrib solution for this (based on http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Styles for example).

What would be the best approach?

[image: Dropdown menu]

Comment: See also this question answered here https://www.drupal.org/node/2303075

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a custom "ckeditor.styles.js" editing the profile > CSS > Predefined styles and also the Predefined Styles Path fields.

[image: CKEditor custom styles configuration]

Additionally, you can override any other CKEditor configuration in Advanced Options > Custom JavaScript configuration